# array modifier query on a textured tile

Tags: texturing

so I worked on one of my first fully textured tiles (it has a UV and a whole setup of nodes for normal, specular and ambiant occlusion maps and a displacement modifier. The problem is when I try to replicate the tile with an array mod, the result seems different and the light also doesn't interact with it in the same way. I'm new to blender and this is the first big setback I've encountered, I've done a lot research but just can't seem to hit the right answer on this one, maybe I'm so new that even the answers I did get, I lack the knowledge to have being able to manage them...   [image]

I hope my image helps, see the difference between the right and the left part. it's the right one that has been produced by the array mod and comes out as a lot darker, that's what I'm trying to resolve.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the texture isn't seamless,can you show the texture and the displacement?

Comment: Can you post a shot of the full material nodetree?

Comment: It may not be ideal, but it can help you identify if there is something truly off between your materials. Try rotating your mesh at the left 180° to make it look mirror imaged from the one at right.

Comment: sry Omar and Todd but I'm not able to put the elements your asking for, somehow the elements fill the screen and puts them on a standalone page with no functions related to the website. I don't know what to do. Thanks for the idea Rick, I did something similar to that, created a duplicate and shifted it, I could settle for that on this little project but I was thinking that when I want to do this on a larger scale, I'm going to to run into the same problem and I won't want to do that then

Comment: I tried to add the information through editing the main post but now it is saying my files are just over 2mb so they can't go through

Comment: I managed to include the texture, unfortunately I'm still unable to include the displacement map and the node tree because I need more than 10 reputation point if I want to put additional links. All I can say is that I watched a the blender guru tutorial and my node tree is basically taken from there.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added your .blend, you can upload it http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  just edit the resulting link into your question. You can combine images with GIMP for example, to include more relevant information to your issue.